# Hiding the progress bar during installation

Tags: java, install4j

I am looking for a way to hide the progress bar during the installation phase (an install4j compiled project).
I did not find how to do it using the install4j IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a form screen with ID "123" that contains a "Progress display" form component with ID "234", you can call

```
((FormPanelContainer)context.getScreenById("123")).getFormEnvironment()
   .getFormComponentById("234").setVisible(false);
```

in order to hide the form component.

In the standard "Installation" screen, it's not possible to hide the progress bar. However, you can set it to the indeterminate state with a "Set the progress bar" action.

Comment: Thanks, i was referring to the standard "Installation" screen.
I will try to use your 'intermediate' suggestion.